# RegEx at most one single quote in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex

I've written a regular expression to accept alpha (a-z) case insensitive, single quote, or hyphen only.

> /^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/

Matches: Marie-Poppins-O'Connor

How can i tweak this further to enforce the following additional rules

1. hyphen and single-quote NOT at the beginning or end
2. at most one single-quote
3. hyphen and quote must not be adjacent to each other (letter must separate them)

Help !

NB: regex dialect is whatever works with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert that at most one single quote occurs:

```
/^(?!.*'.*')(?!.*(?:-'|'-))[A-Za-z](?:[a-zA-Z'-]*[A-Za-z])?$/
```

Sample script:

```js
console.log(/^(?!.*'.*')(?!.*(?:-'|'-))[A-Za-z](?:[a-zA-Z'-]*[A-Za-z])?$/.test("Marie-Poppins-O'Connor"));
console.log(/^(?!.*'.*')(?!.*(?:-'|'-))[A-Za-z](?:[a-zA-Z'-]*[A-Za-z])?$/.test("O'Connor-O'Connor"));
console.log(/^(?!.*'.*')(?!.*(?:-'|'-))[A-Za-z](?:[a-zA-Z'-]*[A-Za-z])?$/.test("'Hello World"));
console.log(/^(?!.*'.*')(?!.*(?:-'|'-))[A-Za-z](?:[a-zA-Z'-]*[A-Za-z])?$/.test("Mary O-'Connor"));
```

Comment: wow that was quick. sorry but I've updated the requirements with 3rd rule no adjacent hyphen and quote, is your regex still valid?

Comment: You may add another negative lookahead to cover that requirement.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but when i Run Code Snippet, it's failing on first match "Marie-Poppins-O'Connor", which is meant to be your pass case ?

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in there, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
const regx = /^(?!.*'.*')(?!.*(?:-'|'-|--|''))[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z'-]*)[A-Za-z]$/;
```

My modified answer (thanks to Tim Biegeleisen's answer which i accepted), rewritten in a way that i can understand.

Essentially there are 3 groups

```
[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z'-]*)[A-Za-z]
```

The above says begin with a-z, optional part in the middle 0 or more times, and end with a-z. (Do i really need the ?: in the group, not sure, feel free to comment).

```
(?!.*(?:-'|'-|--|''))
```

The above says don't allow quote, hyphen, or hyphen-hyphen, or quote-quote to be adjacent

```
 (?!.*'.*')
```

And finally the above says don't allow occurence of quotes twice.

YAY! matches with "Mary-Poppins-Hot-Chick-O'Connor". Minimal pass "Ab"

Comment: I noticed a couple of problems. Firstly, there's no stated prohibition against `'--'` or `"''"` appearing in the string. Secondly, you require the string to contain at least two characters, so it does not match strings consisting of a single letter. No, you don't "need the ?: in the group".

Comment: If you don't want `'--'` or `"''"` to appear in the string you can simplify `(?!.*(?:-'|'-|--|''))` to `(?!.*[-']{2})`. btw, glad to see you taking a crack at modifying Tim's regex. You're very close.

Comment: Thanks for your input Cary, much appreciated :-) Normally i just give up when it comes to regEx, life's to short to fight against them, but i finally understand a tiny bit of lookahead.

Comment: You'll find there's a point where you experience a breakthrough and discover regular expressions are not so mysterious, or their use so difficult, after all. Then it's on to using advanced features, where you need an understanding of how the regex engine works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let regex = /^([A-Za-z]+([A-Za-z-]+)?)?[A-Za-z]'?[A-Za-z](([A-Za-z-]+)?[A-Za-z]+)?)?$/

console.log('aa', regex.test('aa'))
console.log('a-a', regex.test('a-a'))
console.log("a'a", regex.test("a'a"))
console.log("a-'aa", regex.test("a-'aa"))
console.log("a-a'a", regex.test("a-a'a"))
console.log("aaa", regex.test("aaa"))
console.log("a-a'a-a", regex.test("a-a'a-a"))
console.log("a-a'a-a'", regex.test("a-a'a-a'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regular expression (with the case-indifferent flag set) to validate the string.

```
^(?!['-]|.*(?:'-|-'))[a-z-]*'?[a-z-]*[a-z]$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O7Mn3L/2/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^            :match beginning of string
(?!          :begin negative lookahead
  ['-]       :match "'-" or "-'" at beginning of string
  |          :or
  .*         :match 0+ characters
  (?:'-|-')  :match "'-" or "-'" in a non-capture group
)            :end negative lookahead
[a-z-]*      :match 0+ letters or hyphens 
'?           :optionally match single quote
[a-z-]*      :match 0+ letters or hyphens
[a-z]        :match a letter
$            :match end of string
```

Note that this matches a string consisting of a single letter but not an empty string.